# Node webkit window manager on boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, node-webkit

I have written a node webkit application that also works as a window manager.

I want to achieve the following on Ubuntu on boot:

- Bypass Ubuntu loading screen (skip it or customize it)
- Start and display my app instead of and before anything else

Is that possible? And if yes how can it be achieved? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that you are launching node-webkit in kiosk mode?

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/The-Kiosk-mode

To add your app in Ubuntu as apps to start as soon as linux has booted:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-every-time-i-log-in